# How to pass Navigator function as a parameter in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, parameters, routes, navigator

I have this custom widget:

```dart
Widget ButtonsFunction(String text , IconData icon,Function action){
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => action,
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(27.0),
            primary: Colors.grey[300],
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey , width: 0.5),
            elevation: 0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
          ),
          child: Icon(icon , color: Colors.indigo,),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
        Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
      ],
    );
  }
```

*and this call:*

```
ButtonsFunction('Corporate', Icons.wallet,() => Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/CorporateMatters')),
```

But nothing happen when i click on the button, i've tried to write the button code without the function and it works normally but with this function i cant navigate

Answer (score 0):

Call it directly, change this:

```
onPressed: () => action,
```

to this:

```
onPressed: action,
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your custom widget you should trigger the function you are passing.

Like this:

```
onPressed: () => action(),
```

or this:

```
onPressed: () => action.call(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove () => and call directly action and I advise you also to use named parameters for clearer code.

```
onPressed: action,
```

Answer (score 0):

I  prefer  using `VoidCallback` in this case,

```dart
Widget ButtonsFunction(String text, IconData icon, VoidCallback action) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: action,
```

Also note that I am using `onPressed: action,` instead of creating anonymous function like `onPressed: () => action`. If you like to do this way, you need to use `()` to call the method like `onPressed: () => action()`.